ORA-06502: PL/SQL: error : character to number conversion error
Im having trouble while executing this PLSQL:
I've tried but nothing seems to be working for me.
My PLSQL goes like this:
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
declare
l_api_version           NUMBER ;
l_init_msg_list         VARCHAR2(1000);
l_commit                VARCHAR2(1000);
l_validation_level      NUMBER  ;
l_customer_trx_id       ra_customer_trx.customer_trx_id%type;
lx_return_status        VARCHAR2(1000);
lx_msg_count            NUMBER;
lx_msg_data             VARCHAR2(2000);

L_TIPO NUMBER;
L_GCC NUMBER;
L_NC_ID NUMBER := 4855753;
begin

MO_GLOBAL.SET_POLICY_CONTEXT('S',281);
fnd_global.APPS_INITIALIZE(user_id=>7028,resp_id=>51944,resp_appl_id=>222);

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NOT COMPLETE');

select  cust_trx_type_id , TO_NUMBER(GL_ID_REC) 
INTO L_TIPO,L_GCC
from ra_cust_trx_types_all where NAME = 'NC B 0018 VI Closed';


AR_TRANSACTION_GRP.INCOMPLETE_TRANSACTION(
      p_api_version           =>'1.0',
      p_init_msg_list         =>fnd_api.g_true,
      p_commit                =>fnd_api.g_true,
      p_validation_level      =>fnd_api.g_valid_level_none,
      p_customer_trx_id       =>L_NC_ID,
      x_return_status         =>Lx_return_status,
      x_msg_count             =>Lx_msg_counT,
      x_msg_data              =>Lx_msg_data);

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Lx_return_status '||Lx_return_status);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Lx_msg_counT '||Lx_msg_counT);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Lx_msg_data '||Lx_msg_data);

IF Lx_return_status = 'S' THEN

  update ra_customer_trx_all 
     set cust_trx_type_id = L_TIPO,
         doc_sequence_value =L_NC_ID
   where customer_trx_id = L_NC_ID;

   UPDATE RA_CUST_TRX_LINE_GL_DIST_ALL 
      SET CODE_COMBINATION_ID = L_GCC
    WHERE CUSTOMER_tRX_ID = L_NC_ID
      AND ACCOUNT_CLASS = 'REC';

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('COMPLETO');

AR_TRANSACTION_GRP.COMPLETE_TRANSACTION(
      p_api_version           =>'1.0',
      p_init_msg_list         =>fnd_api.g_true,
      p_commit                =>fnd_api.g_true,
      p_validation_level      =>fnd_api.g_valid_level_none,
      p_customer_trx_id       =>L_NC_ID,
      x_return_status         =>Lx_return_status,
      x_msg_count             =>Lx_msg_counT,
      x_msg_data              =>Lx_msg_data);


DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Lx_return_status '||Lx_return_status);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Lx_msg_counT '||Lx_msg_counT);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Lx_msg_data '||Lx_msg_data);

  update ra_customer_trx_all 
     set doc_sequence_value =NULL
   where customer_trx_id = L_NC_ID;

      
END IF;      
      
COMMIT;

end;

Got this error message:
06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"
*Cause:    An arithmetic, numeric, string, conversion, or constraint error
           occurred. For example, this error occurs if an attempt is made to
           assign the value NULL to a variable declared NOT NULL, or if an
           attempt is made to assign an integer larger than 99 to a variable
           declared NUMBER(2).
*Action:   Change the data, how it is manipulated, or how it is declared so
           that values do not violate constraints.

Its sats error at line 26 and thats line is empty and below that this sentence:
AR_TRANSACTION_GRP.INCOMPLETE_TRANSACTION(.
What am i missing? am i doing anything wrong?

The line number is for the PL/SQL block, and does not include the SET SERVEROUTPUT ON line, which is a SQL*Plus command. So the line number does perfectly match the call to AR_TRANSACTION_GRP.INCOMPLETE_TRANSACTION. Compare the data types of the procedure with the variables in you PL/SQL block. In SQL*Plus, you can use the command desc AR_TRANSACTION_GRP, although this kind of debugging would be much easier with an IDE.

Used p_api_version           =>1.0,
instead of p_api_version           =>'1.0' and worked :)
